# How to ensure that Room DB populates database only once?

Tags: android, android-room

In my applications splash screen I run a Thread to populate a database, but it populates the database with same items everytime I open the app, I don't want to put a boolean flag like `isFirstTime` then set it to false after I populate the db, is there another solution?

here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Home {
    public @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;
    private int homeCode;
    private String homeName;

    public Bank(int homeCode, String homeName) {
        this.homeCode = homeCode;
        this.homeName = homeName;
    }

    int getHomeCode() {
        return homeCode;
    }

    public void setHomeCode(int homeCode) {
        this.homeCode = homeCode;
    }
....
}
```

do you think `autogenerating the primary key` is the issue? maybe room thinks it gets different items since their primary keys are different?

Comment: isn't that the entity not dao? may you show dao?

Comment: yep my bad, doesnt change my question though

Comment: How are you pre-populating your database? The recommended way is to use:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Callback.html

Answer (score 0):

no autogenerating the primary key is not problem to create duplicates. 
i provide one way to used and i think solved your problem.
make one class for extend application like below ...

```
public class AppActivity extends Application {

static AppDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
}

public static AppDatabase getDatabase() {
    return db;
}
```

}

and this class call in mainfest file in applcation tag like below..

```
        android:name=".db.AppActivity" // application tag in.
```

Comment: Yeah but I do it like this aswell

Answer (score 0):

You can relay on **onCreate** [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Callback.html#onCreate(android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)). It is called when the database is created for the first time. When you instantiate room, just call **addCallback**.

Example:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
AppDatabase provideDatabase(Application application) {
    return Room
            .databaseBuilder(application, AppDatabase.class, BuildConfig.DB_NAME)
            .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onCreate(db);
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put("title", "Test 1");
                    contentValues.put("content", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec qu");
                    contentValues.put("type", 0);
                    contentValues.put("date", 1525421352);
                    db.insert(NotificationEntity.TABLE_NAME, OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, contentValues);

                    contentValues.put("title", "Test 2");
                    contentValues.put("content", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec.");
                    contentValues.put("type", 1);
                    contentValues.put("date", 1225421242);
                    db.insert(NotificationEntity.TABLE_NAME, OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, contentValues);

                    contentValues.put("title", "Test 3");
                    contentValues.put("content", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a");
                    contentValues.put("type", 2);
                    contentValues.put("date", 1525000242);
                    db.insert(NotificationEntity.TABLE_NAME, OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, contentValues);

                    contentValues.put("title", "Test 4");
                    contentValues.put("content", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibu");
                    contentValues.put("type", 3);
                    contentValues.put("date", 1520420000);
                    db.insert(NotificationEntity.TABLE_NAME, OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE, contentValues);

                }
            })
            .build();
}
```